# C++, child with both parents having a same ancestor

Tags: c++, class, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

I'm having trouble with C++ classes and inheritance right now...

Let's say we have

```
Class A {
A(string name);
    ~A();
    void func(void);
}
Class B : public A {
    B(string name);
    ~B();
    ...
}
Class C : public A {
    C(string name);
    ~C();
    ...
}
Class D : public B, public D {
    D(string name);
    ~D();
    ...
}
```

Whenever I create `D`, it calls the constructor for `B` and the one for `C` which results in multiple instances of `A`. The compiler then says it doesn't know which "func" it should call, the one from `B` or the one from `C`.

I would like to know how to call `A` constructor ONLY ONCE and then use it to build `B` and `C`.

I already tried using `B::func()` to be able to call `func()` but has I must have a cout in the class A builder. It results in wrong output.

Comment: Search for virtual inheritance.

Comment: Do you mean `Class D : public B, public D ` or `class D : public B, public C `?

Comment: This is the common [*diamond inheritance pattern*](https://www.makeuseof.com/what-is-diamond-problem-in-cpp/).

Comment: I doubt, that creation of D would invoke any constructor of C as there is no connection between them at all. Maybe it´s a typo in your question in class D constructor?

Comment: Read more about [virtual inheritance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class).

Comment: your code is riddled with typos and compiler errors. Fwiw, you can call `B::func`, no problem, https://godbolt.org/z/dnEeMqqcr

Comment: This is a classic design problem with diamond inheritance : [The diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance). And I would advise you to look for a different design. Look in the mitigation section on that page.

Comment: I would expect that any C++ textbook that gives such a practice problem would explain the specific C++ concept that works like this. Also it's completely unclear what exactly is being asked about, this can be interpreted as a question about one of two different core C++ fundamentals. What is the topic of this chapter in your C++ textbook where this coding problem is from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the **diamond inheritance pattern**.
In order to avoid having 2 instances of `A` in `D`, you need to use [**virtual inheritance**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class).
When classes e.g. `B` virtually inherit `A`, it means that `A` will be present only once in a class derived from those classes.
Note: in this case it is the responsibility of the most derived class to initialize the virtual base(s) - as shown below.

The output from the following code demonstrates it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A {
public:
    A(std::string const & name) { std::cout << "A::A\n"; };
    ~A() {};
    void func(void);
};
//--------vvvvvvv-----------
class B : virtual public A {
public:
    B(std::string const& name) : A(name) { std::cout << "B::B\n"; };
    ~B() {};
};
//--------vvvvvvv-----------
class C : virtual public A {
public:
    C(std::string const& name) : A(name) { std::cout << "C::C\n"; };
    ~C() {};
};
class D : public B, public C {
public:
//-------------------------------vvvvvvv---------------------------------------------
    D(std::string const& name) : A(name), B(name), C(name) { std::cout << "D::D\n"; };
    ~D() {};
};

int main()
{
    D d("aaa");
}
```

Output:

```
A::A
B::B
C::C
D::D
```

I.e. `A` is present once in `D`.

Note that if you remove the `virtual` keyword, the output will be:

```
A::A
B::B
A::A
C::C
D::D
```

I.e. `A` is present twice in `D` (as you observed).

---

**Some side notes:**

1. Better to avoid `using namespace std` - see here [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).
2. Your code contains many typos: `Class` should be `class`, missing `;` at the end of classes.
3. You constructors can accept the `name` by `const &` as demonstrated in my code, to avoid copy.